# Defines.Debug vs #if DEBUG

Tags: c#

I've started to use a define class like so:

```
internal sealed class Defines
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This constant is set to true iff the define DEBUG is set.
    /// </summary>
    public const bool Debug =
  #if DEBUG
   true;
  #else
   false;
  #endif
}
```

The advantages I see is:

1. Ensures I don't break stuff that with an #if..#else..#endif would not be checked by compiler.
2. I can do a find references to see where it is used.
3. It's often useful to have a bool for debug, defines code is longer/more messy.

Possible disadvantage I see:

Compiler can't optimize unused code if the Defines class is in another assembly. Which is why I have made internal.

Am I missing any other disadvantages?

[Edit] Typical examples of usage:

```
private readonly Permissions _permissions = Defines.Debug ? Permissions.NewAllTrue()
                                                          : Permissions.NewAllFalse();
```

Or:

```
var str = string.Format(Defines.Debug ? "{0} {1} ({2})" : "{0} {1}", actual, text, advance);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) at all?

Comment: @Oded Thanks, I've added typical examples, just small modifications in single lines, not whole methods or classes which the ConditionalAttribute suits, or should I just not be so lazy and define two methods for these lines?

Comment: What happens if the assembly containing this is build in `Debug` but those that reference it are built in `Release`?

Comment: Well that would be the same scenario as if I used #if DEBUG. Are you suggesting the ConditionalAttribute solves that and that all assemblies run with the conditionals from the exe assembly, however they are built?

Comment: No, not at all. But I just want to highlight the problems with any sort of such construct.

Comment: OK, well I use a buildserver so thankfully I can not worry about mixed build assemblies being shipped. But point taken anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see at least one big disadvantage: if `Debug` is false, this code will cause a warning:

```
if (Debug)
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
```

Because the compiler will detect that the condition is never met, so the `Console.WriteLine` call is unreachable.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's very annoying. I think I'll look into @Oded s suggestion then.